# PowerQuery: How can I concatenate grouped values?

Tags: excel, group-by, powerquery, excel-2016, m

If I have the following table (shown in the image below), how can I write a grouped query that would concatenate the grouped results?

[image: InputTable]

For this example, I'd want to group by the `LetterColumn` and concatenate the `NumberColumn`

So the desired results would be:

[image: ResultsTable]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your table is Source, and if NumberColumn has the number type, then this will work:

`= Table.Group(Source, {"LetterColumn"}, {{"Column", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_[NumberColumn], (x) => Number.ToText(x)), ","), type text}})`

`Table.Group` does a group by operation, which creates a table made up of all of the rows with the same value in LetterColumn. `_[NumberColumn]` gives a list of the values in the NumberColumn column in this new table. The `List.Transform` part turns the numbers into text values, and `Text.Combine` joins those numbers together, with a comma separating each value.

If you need the surrounding quotes as well, you can do this:

`= Table.Group(Source, {"LetterColumn"}, {{"Column", each """" & Text.Combine(List.Transform(_[NumberColumn], (x) => Number.ToText(x)), ",") & """", type text}})`

`""""` represents the " character, and & combines two text values.

Answer (score 70):

You can use the GUI to do it this way:

1. Select your LetterColumn and then Transform / GroupBy:
   [image]
2. Select Add Column / Custom Column:
   [image]
3. Click opposing arrows at top right of new Custom column to Extract Values from new Custom column:

[image]
[image]

4. Remove AllData column.

Comment: Genius! How did you find that [AllData][NumberColumn] syntax?  I've been working with this tool for 4 years and never seen that before.

Comment: I honestly don't recall @MikeHoney, but I might have seen it in a response from marcelbeug in the past. I've learned a heck of a lot from him. Either that...or I just tried it and it worked. ;0)

Comment: Holy crap this is genius

Comment: 1. This is absolute genius!
2. WTF doesn't Excel just have a simple join function?

Comment: Here it is 2020, and I run into to problems.  (I'm using Office 365.)
1.  The GUI approach (from @MarcPincince) doesn't work for me, even when I try it on Giffyguy's original data.  The column that results from step 2 creates a column that says 'Error' in every row.  Maybe Get & Transform has changed?  It would be great if we could use GUI...
2. Using the formula provided by @Alejandro in 'Custom Column' works great...BUT my problem is the data I'm trying to concatenate is text, not number.  Have tried to adapt the formula accordingly but haven't succeeded...any ideas?

Comment: @P E, I too am using O365 and I just now worked through the steps exactly as I have shown in my original response, using Giffyguy's original data, and it worked fine. I also switched from [AllData][NumberColumn] to [AllData][LetterColumn] and that worked fine as well. I have no idea why you are experiencing a problem with the GUI.

Comment: @P E, Alternative to using the GUI. You can use this code. Just change _#"Changed Type"_ to the name of the preceding step, change _"LetterColumn"_ to whatever column you want to group by, and change _[NumberColumn]_ to the column you want to concatenate the values of. `= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"LetterColumn"}, {{"AllData", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([NumberColumn], Text.From), ","), type number}})`

Comment: @MarcPincince, I also used your approach successfully for over a year, but just saw the same issue as @P E in O365. I believe PQ is generating incorrect list expansion. I see this: `each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ...)` - literally dot dot dot, despite having chosen comma. If I change `...` to `","`, world order is restored...

Comment: Interesting @JerryNorbury. Thanks for sharing that  bit about the ...

Comment: Fantastic! Just Fantastic Thanks very much! Good job!!!

Comment: I tried for a couple of hours to figure out how to do this in DAX. I had some ideas around using PATH. Almost glad I didn't figure it out. This is a great solution. I can see this being used all over the place in my Power BI models. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Excel newbie here. In the extracting values from the list step, how to extract only the distinct values from the list and concatenate them?

Comment: @Shiva, click the *Extracted Values* step that results from what you do by following what I showed above and try changing the formula that appears in the formula bar from  `= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})` to 
`= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Transform(_, Text.From)), ","), type text})`. You should see the *Extracted Values* step in the Applied Steps, on the right side of your screen. Click it, then look at the top of your screen for the formula bar.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if the GUI had a "Combine Text" operation.  However, there is a small adjustment from operation **Sum** and selecting the Column:

[image]

We get straight to this, almost what we want:

[image]

```
= Table.Group(Source, 
    {"LetterColumn"}, 
    {{"NearlyGoodToGo", each List.Sum([NumberColumn]), type number}})
```

Now, two changes directly in the code:

- Replace `List.Sum[NumberColumn]` with
  `Text.Combine(List.Transform([NumberColumn], Text.From), ",")`
- Replace `type number` with `type text`

I see this as using the GUI for the hard part, to get a basic template, but then adjusting the code to avoid extra steps with the GUI's All Rows operation and the nested tables it produces.

**Demo**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({{"A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"},{1..9}}, type table[LetterColumn = Text.Type, NumberColumn = Number.Type]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"LetterColumn"}, {{"GoodToGo", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([NumberColumn], Text.From), ","), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Results**

[image]