# Excel Query to combine multiple rows across multiple CSVs based on timestamp

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 85 large CSV files. Each contains rows with timestamps, a tag, and several values. I've created a Query for the folder containing these CSVs. I want to combine rows based on the timestamps so that there is a single row for each time and then additional columns that contain the tags and values. I can't bring everything back into excel since there are millions of rows. Is there a way to merge these?

Here are some example rows from the Query. I would want to combine the first 18 rows for example into a single row for 1/10/2016 12:00:00 AM.

[image]

Comment: The solution can use something like the approaches mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058355/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values

Comment: can you send the sample excel file with the cvs files ? (just a few rows of data will be enough)

Comment: What do you mean "to combine"? You want to sum Values, for example? Or maybe you want to get value's average? And what to do with text strings like Tagname? Concatenate?