# PowerQuery: How can I concatenate MULTIPLE grouped values

Tags: powerquery

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058355/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values/44058791#44058791), and I would comment to ask @marc-pincince but I don't have the reputation require.

Would this be adaptable for 3 columns of data?
I have column A, B, C.

- A = ID
- B = Award
- C = Year

What I need is to have new column A which groups all the ID's and then new column B which shows Award Year, Award Year, Award Year, Award Year , etc..

I tried using The Custom Column using `=[AllData][Award][Year]`
Also tried using `=[AllData]([Award]+[Year])`

Both of these result in errors. I was able to get `[AllData][Award]` and `[AllData][Year]` to work seperately.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a column that concatenates the Award and Year together. To do this, make sure both of those columns are a text data type and then create a custom column `[AwardYear]` using the formula `= [Award] & " " & [Year]`.

Once you do that, you can follow the same steps as in the other question, except you'll use `[AllData][AwardYear]` for your custom column.