# Merging two tables and a concatenation too - Power BI Q

Tags: dynamic, powerbi

I am getting ready to perform a merge in Power BI of two tables. Two fields in my merge need to be rolled up into one field.

[image]

The two fields in the tsg_variations table need to be concatenated into the tsg_enquiries.tsg_enquirynumber field.  How do I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to do this using DAX or in the Query Editor?

Comment: The query editor was the route I was perusing, Alexis Olson.

Comment: You can also check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783240/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-grouped-values