# Excel Powerquery group by text

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'd like to be able to convert text over multiple rows with a common field to a single field over multiple columns.

from this:
[image]
to this:
[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerQuery: How can I concatenate grouped values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058355/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values)

Answer (score 0):

### It's very easy =)

[image]

```
let
    src = #table({"col1", "col2"}, {
        {"1","a"},{"1","b"},{"1","c"},
        {"2","a"},{"2","b"},{"2","c"}}
    ),
    grouped = Table.Group(src, {"col1"}, {{"col2", each Text.Combine([col2], ",")}})
in
    grouped
```

[image]