# How to use CONCATENATEX or similar function to get Distinct ID with many types in POWER BI

Tags: concatenation, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I tried classic formulation of `CONCATENATEX`, but it didnt work.

I need calculate this table

```
ID  TYPE
1   A
1   B
2   B
3   A
4   A
4   A
4   A
4   C
4   D
4   E
5   B
5   B
6   A
7   A
7   B
7   C
8   B
8   B
9   D
10  A
10  A
10  D
```

to this table

```
ID  TYPES
1   A,B
2   B
3   A
4   A,A,A,C,D,E
5   B,B
6   A
7   A,B,C
8   B,B
9   D
10  A,A,D
```

Looked for answer in exceltown, didnt help.

```
kombi = CONCTENATEX(TABLE;TYPE;"+")
```

I expect result A+B or A+A+A, or A+C, but results be like

> A+A+A+A+A+B+B+B+B+B+C+C+C+C+B+B+B+B+B+A+A+A+A++D+D+D+

[image]

Comment: You can refer this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058355/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values

Comment: Your formula is perfectly fine, the visual in which you evaluate it causes your problem. I assume you are trying a table visual with one column ID and another the measure [kombi]? Make sure ID is set to the aggregation 'don't summarize'. It will result in a list of IDs and the proper evaluation of your measure. By default, it is usually is summed as ID often get recognized as integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Step 1 -> Screenshot 1]
[image: Step 2 -> Screenshot 2]

[image: Step 3 -> Screenshot 3]

You can use the below power query to get the desired result.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("c:\Desktop\stac.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"TYPE", type text}, {"ID", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type1",{{"ID", type text}, {"TYPE", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"All Rows", each _, type table [ID=text, TYPE=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows1", "Custom", each [All Rows][TYPE]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "+"), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"All Rows"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to write that I need it in Power BI , excel cant process big data set. (file has about 200MB in excel)

Comment: When you open the power bi you will be having edit query option, where you can write power query(M Query) to do data manipulation. In power query you can paste this query using advance editor option and change only the source file as mentioned

Comment: I have added step file screenshot to do it in powerbi

Comment: It works, I am sorry I need 10 more reputation to give you upvote, but you can expect it. Im curious How can I add DISTINCT: For example row 4 from picture is 4 - A,A,A,C,D,E i want to transform it to 4 - A,C,D,E