# SQL: How can I concatenate grouped values?

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have the following table (shown in the image below), how can I write SQL code that would concatenate the grouped results?

[image]

For this example, I'd want to group by the LetterColumn and concatenate the NumberColumn

So the desired results would be:

[image]

Note: Same question has been posted not for SQL but for Power Query here:
[PowerQuery: How can I concatenate grouped values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058355/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values)

Comment: You need to write a UDF to do this or to write the code in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a small VBA procedure that does the grouping of the number column for a given letter (without the quotes, which would be trivial to add):

```
Public Function fGroupColumn(strLetter As String) As String
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT NumberColumn FROM tblColumn WHERE LetterColumn='" & strLetter & "' ORDER BY NumberColumn ASC;"
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
        Do
            fGroupColumn = fGroupColumn & rsData!NumberColumn & ","
            rsData.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsData.EOF
    End If
    If Right(fGroupColumn, 1) = "," Then fGroupColumn = Left(fGroupColumn, Len(fGroupColumn) - 1)
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fGroupColumn", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

You can then use this function within an Access query to get the result that you want.

Regards,