# powerquery bug? Order of concatenated list changes in subsequent step

Tags: powerquery

I am using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058791/1381490) to concatenate a list of values per group. Before grouping I sorted the group field and the value field in ascending order.
this is the result after concatenating (column [Custom]):

[image]

In a following step I expand one column of the table in the last column, causing the [Custom] column to change sorting... ???

[image]

This is the content of the dd_center_tbi_variable column:

[image]

Comment: Can you show here what is the content of `dd_center_tbl_variable` table before expanding?

Comment: @smpa01, see my edit