# Power Query - Columns as separate unrelated list (from unpivoted data)

Tags: excel, pivot, powerquery, m

If I have a simple unpivoted list like this:

| Names | Subjects |
| --- | --- |
| John | English |
| Sam | Art |
| Fred | Biology |
| John | Biology |
| Emma | Art |
| Mike | Biology |

How can I create a list like this where the rows are unrelated to each other and each column is almost a separate list? Pivoting doesn't work - is this possible?

| Art | Biology | English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emma | Fred | John |
| Sam | John | null |
| null | Mike | null |

Thanks

Comment: Follow the steps in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058355/powerquery-how-can-i-concatenate-grouped-values then split the last column by delimiter, and transpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to group and add an index before pivoting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Names", type text}, {"Subjects", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Subjects"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Names=nullable text, Subjects=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All], "Index")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"All"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Names", "Index"}, {"Names", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Subjects]), "Subjects", "Names"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as an exercise, without grouping:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Ans = let s1=Table.Column(Source, "Subjects"), 
              s2=List.Sort(List.Distinct(s1)), 
              n1=Table.Column(Source, "Names"), 
              x=List.Numbers(0,List.Count(n1)), 
              n2=List.Transform(s2,(y)=>List.Accumulate(x,{},(s,c)=>if s1{c}=y then List.Combine({s,{n1{c}}}) else s)),
              m=List.Numbers(0,List.Max(List.Transform(n2,(z)=>List.Count(z)))),
              r1=List.Transform(m,(q)=>Record.FromList(List.Accumulate(s2,{},(s,c)=>List.Combine({s,{try n2{List.PositionOf(s2,c)}{q} otherwise null}})),s2)),
              t1=Table.FromRecords(r1)
          in t1
in
    Ans
```

[image]